# How to get an accurate edge value of gaussian scipy

Tags: filters, python, gaussian

i am new to this forum and I am not sure which topic I have to use. But I think my problem belongs to signal processing.

My problem is the following one. I try using filter to find the actual momentum of stocks. First i used a moving average but it was by far too slow. Than I found the gaussin filter 1d which I use from scipy in python. The result is much better now but it is pretty inaccurate at the edges (last value). It seems that the calculation somehow weights too much the last value. Let me show:

If I am using the gaussian filter on historical data the result looks pretty smooth:
[image: Python gaussian on historical data]

On the other hand if I apply the same filter on live data it looks different, more edgy and delayed:
[image: Python gaussian filter on live data]

In my opinion the last calculated values seem to fluctuate too much. Therefore I tried different modes like mirror, nearest, etc. But mirror seems to give the best result.

Python scipy function:
gaussian_filter1d(data, 7, mode='mirror')

How do i get the last calculated value of the filter more accurate?

Comment: hi! I'm not versed in financial mathematics, so let me ask about a few definitions of words you use, please: What is "actual momentum"? What is "the last value"; could you explain that as formula or in your graphs? How do you measure "accuracy" of a result here?

Comment: Hi sure.  For momentum i use a quote of wikipedia: In finance, momentum is the empirically observed tendency for rising asset prices to rise further. The last value is the last known datapoint from the stock exchange. Newer values are not known yet (future). If we check the graph from above the last known value would be datapoint 113 2,086 with timestamp Sat Jun 19 07:51:40 2021. Accury could be the difference from the calculated values on historical data and live data (green line from first graph and green line from second graph).

Comment: ah, so it's not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_(technical_analysis) ? (also, I generally mistrust wikipedia definitions when they are as vague as "observed tendency to rise further": I mean, rising further is a thing in the future. How can you *observe* that? You could only do that after the fact, right? so, hm, I feel like this definition is either not saying very much, or could be a lot more technical.)

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound dismissive, I don't mean to. It's just that you're asking us to help you optimize something, and to do that, we need to understand a metric of goodness – otherwise, there's nothing to optimize! Now, I don't understand the model of goodness here - it seems to me that it needs to be something probabilistic like an expected value for price? change? relative change? condition on previous observation, and it feels like there's a lot of implicit stochastic model that I don't know – that's why I'm asking you about what "momentum" is so naggingly.

Comment: Technically you are right. You cannot predict the future. I have to say that i don't have a financial backround, I am an system engineer. Therefore I just can say what I understood. Movement of direction seems to have lots of inertia. What I am looking for is the direction of movement (rising or falling).

Comment: wouldn't that just be the derivative, then?

Comment: Come on. If the gaussian filter would give a function I could do so. But i don't need to if I just apply a logic on the result f(x-1) < f(x).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I really don't mean to sound mean, or anything! I'm still stumbling in the dark what a momentum is, and you have not given us anything to define that. How are we going to find a good formula for estimating it if we don't even have an idea of what it is? "It's a pretty curve that goes up when the stock prices go up" is not really something we can do "well" or "better". There's literally uncountably infinitely many pretty curves!